# DynamoDB - Does deleting a secondary index induce cost?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB Table with a lot of data already, and I want to delete a secondary index that I don't use anymore. Will this induce cost?

Comment: is it a local secondary index or a Global secondary index. Deleting a GSI does reduce cost.

Comment: I asked a wrong question, i mean is deleting a secondary index will induce cost? @RajanPrasad

Answer (score 0):

After searching, there is no cost in deleting secondary index. :D